# Doing contracting work in a foreign country, who are taxes owed?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, ukraine

I have a question about taxes in relation to the following:

- A British citizen has a work permit in a foreign country (Ukraine). They work full time here.
- They also do contracting work remotely for an American company earning a US dollar salary into a US bank account whilst based in Ukraine.
- They have been out of their home country (UK) for 2 years and therefore are a non-resident.

Who do they pay taxes to on the money earned through contracting?

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, they should be paying taxes to the country where they have lived 183 days continuous most recently. It's a standard which most countries follow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).